# downloading a build artifact on a remote machine

Tags: build, jenkins, download, cloudbees, artifact

I build artifacts on jenkins builds on cloudbees and for dev and test env (which are on Run@Cloud) the deployments are done from Jenkins.

However for production deployments, I would need to download the artifact (as URL) on the production machine. is there a way to set this up so that it does not ask for cloudbees login.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want artifacts to be public you need some credentials to access cloudbees jenkins (this isn't a FOSS project, is it ?)

You can use jenkins token to authenticate, so you don't need to publish your cloudbees password on production server. 
See  https://[account].ci.cloudbees.com/user/[me@mycompany.com]/configure to retrieve token, then you can access jenkins using

```
wget http://[me%40mycompany.com]:[token]@<account>.ci.cloudbees.com/...
```

Comment: thanks nicolas, it isnt a foss, (I know foss is public and we dont need to run into this case). however I have tried accessing an artifact with the api token method that you have specified, but it did not work, curl downloaded the content of the login page as the download artifact.

Comment: I think you need wget as it will follow redirects (there is some SSO redirection that goes on).